# relative URL paths when serving static files with FastAPI/Starlette

Tags: static-files, fastapi, starlette

I have a simple FastAPI application that serves a file `test.html` in `app/main.py` like so:

```
@app.get('/')
def index():
  return FileResponse('static/test.html')
```

The directory structure is like so:

```
app/main.py
app/static/test.html
```

Can I change this do that it works with a modified directory structure where `app/` and `static/` are siblings?

I have tried `return FileResponse('../static/test.html')` but that has not worked so far; the resulting error is "RuntimeError: File at path ../static/test.html does not exist."

Comment: Related answers with regard to serving static files in FastAPI can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804).

Answer (score 2):

If your 'static' dir is in the same dir as your main.py
Try:

```
return FileResponse('./static/test.txt')
```

Looks like you were looking in the folder above.

you could could os.path to get the parent dir

```
import os 
parent_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

@app.get('/')
def index():
  return FileResponse(parent_dir_path + '/static/test.html')
```

Comment: Yes, this almost does it; there is an `os.pardir` missing in the calculation of `parent_dir_path`.

Comment: Hey, this works for me but files show up as name "download" with extension. How do I force files to be returned with the correct name? Thanks.

Comment: exactly the correct answer. this helped me get the correct path as report on the FastAPI github here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/376

Answer (score 1):

My proposal: then you have *static* mounted.

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
st_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "static/")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=st_abs_file_path), name="static")
```

or use without that:

```
return FileResponse(st_abs_file_path + 'test.html')
```

More explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69401919/5824889