# RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist") RuntimeError: Directory 'app/static' does not exist

Tags: python

Getting error when i run server.py file

```
File "C:\Users\nawin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\starlette\staticfiles.py", line 57, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist")
RuntimeError: Directory 'app/static' does not exist
```

server.py file

```
app = Starlette()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['*'], allow_headers=['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type'])
app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='app/static'))
```

python version 3.8
os windows 10

Comment: But does the directory exist?

Comment: try using an absolute path instead of 'app/static' to see if that works.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to known the execution path for your program (for **GNU/Linux** environment):

If you have a working directory like this: `~/working/myprogram`

## First case

1. First access to your working directory: `cd ~/working/myprogram`
2. Execute: `python3 mysuper.py`

Then you can execute without any problems.

## Second case

But if you are in another directory:

1. Go to Desktop folder: `cd ~/Desktop`
2. Execute: `python3 ~/working/myprogram/mysuper.py`

In this second case you will get the problem. To avoid this, one proposal (is ugly) but can be:

```py
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
st_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "static/")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=st_abs_file_path), name="static")
```