# How to load a different file than index.html in FastAPI root path while using StaticFiles?

Tags: python, fastapi, static-files, starlette, fileresponse

Here is a simple static FastAPI app. With this setup even though the root path is expected to return a `FileResponse` of `custom.html`, the app still returns `index.html`. How can I get the root path work and render `custom.html`?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()


app.mount(
    "/",
    StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True),
    name="static",
)

@app.get("/")
async def index() -> FileResponse:
    return FileResponse("custom.html", media_type="html")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per Starlette [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/):

> **StaticFiles**
>
> Signature: `StaticFiles(directory=None, packages=None, check_dir=True)`
>
> - `html` - Run in HTML mode. Automatically loads `index.html` for    directories if such file exists.

In addtion, as shown from the code snippet you provided, you have mounted `StaticFiles` to the root directory (i.e., `/`), instead of, for example, `/static` (or some other path name), as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')
```

As per FastAPI [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#what-is-mounting):

> "Mounting" means adding a complete **"independent"** application in a
> specific path, that then **takes care of handling all the sub-paths**.

Hence,  any path that starts with `/` will be handled by that `StaticFiles` application, and due to specifying `html=True` in the arguments, `index.html` will be automatically loaded; **regardless** of creating a separate endpoint pointing to the root path `/` and trying to return something else, as demonstrated in the example given in your question.

### Order Matters

If, for example, you moved `app.mount("/",StaticFiles(...` line **after** defining your `@app.get("/")` endpoint, you would see that [**order matters**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters) and `index.html` would **not** automatically be loaded anymore, as **endpoints are evaluated in order**. Note that, in your case, you might get an `Internal Server Error`, as your `@app.get("/")` endpoint would be called and attempt to find `custom.html`, but if this file is not located under the root `/` directory, but rather under `/static` directory (as shown from your code), you would then get a `File does not exist` error, and hence, you should instead return `FileResponse('static/custom.html')`.

Even if you removed `html=True`, but keep `StaticFiles` mounted to the root directory and defined **before** your `/` endpoint, you would get a `{"detail":"Not Found"}` error response when attempting to access `http://localhost:8000/`. This is because the `/` route would still be handled by the `StaticFiles` application (as mentioned earlier), and you should thus need to specify the file that you would like to access (when `html=True` is not used), e.g., `http://localhost:8000/index.html`. Even if you defined other endpoints in your code (e.g., `/register`, `/login`, `/hello`), as long as `StaticFiles` is mounted to the root directory (i.e., `/`) and defined in your code **before** all other endpoints, for instance:

```py
app.mount('/', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')

@app.post('/register')
async def register():
    pass

@app.post('/login')
async def login():
    pass

@app.get('/hello')
async def hello():
    pass
```

**every request** to those routes would again be handled by the `StaticFiles` application, and hence, would lead to an error response, such as `{"detail":"Not Found"}` (if you send a `GET` request, such as when you type a URL in the address bar of the browser and then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and the given path does not match a file name in the `static` web directory), or `{detail": "Method Not Allowed"}` (if you issue a `POST` request through Swagger UI or some other client platform/application). As described in [Starlette's documentation on `StaticFiles`](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/) (see [`StaticFiles` class implementation](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0c4b68ac4e179a788e38bac28f299dcad0f36e99/starlette/staticfiles.py#L38) as well):

> Static files will respond with `404 Not found` or `405 Method not allowed` responses for requests which **do not match**. In HTML mode, if
> `404.html` file exists, it will be shown as 404 response.

Hence, you should either mount the `StaticFiles` instance to a different/unique path, such as `/static` (i.e., `app.mount('/static', ...`, as shown at the top of this answer), or, if you still want to mount the `StaticFiles` instance to `/` path, define `StaticFiles` **after** declaring all your API endpoints, for example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/register')
async def register():
    pass


@app.post('/login')
async def login():
    pass


@app.get('/hello')
async def hello():
    pass


@app.get('/')
async def index():
    return FileResponse('static/custom.html')
 
 
app.mount('/',StaticFiles(directory='static', html=True), name='static')
```

#### Note

Every time a webpage is loaded, the browser caches most content on the page, in order to shorten laod times (the next time that user loads the page). Thus, if you tried out the example provided earlier, i.e., where the `StaticFiles` application is defined **before** every API endpoint, and then, using the same browser session, you tried out the example above with the `StaticFiles` application defined **after** all API endpoints, but the browser still displays the content of `static/index.html` file instead of `static/custom.html`—when accessing `http://localhost:8000/` in your browser—this is due to the browser loading the webpage from the cache. To overcome this, you could either clear your browser's cache, or open the webpage in an Incognito window (and close it when you are done with it), or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, instead of just <kbd>F5</kbd>,  in your browser (using either an Incognito or regular window), which would force the browser to retrieve the webpage from the server instead of loading it from the cache.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) helpful, regarding the order of endpoints in FastAPI.

### The `html=True` option

Setting the `html` argument of `StaticFiles` instance to `True` (i.e., `html=True`) simply provides an easy way to serve a directory of web content with just one line of code. If you **only** need to serve static files, such as package docs directory, then this is the way to go. If, however, you need to serve different HTML files that will get dynamically updated, as well as you wish to create additional routes/endpoints, you should better have a look at [`Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) (**not** [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse)), as well as mount your `StaticFiles` instance to a **different** path (e.g., `/static`), rather than root path (and without using `html=True`).