# Can't figure out how to assign directory for static files

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I've been trying to mount an HTML file to my localhost when hosting on uvicorn, googled a way with static files, doesn't seem to work for me.
Code :

```
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException
import uvicorn
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

@app.get('/income')
def view_income():
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM income """)
    income = cursor.fetchall()
    return {"data": income}

app.mount ('/', StaticFiles(directory='static', html=True), name="static")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8000')
```

When trying to go to the URL 127.0.0.1:8000/index.html, it's showing detail: not found.
My root folder is app.

Tried changing directories without a clue as to what I'm doing, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Already solved, but thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: Close the question (select an answer) if it is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your folder structure is set up correctly. You mentioned that your root folder is named "app," and you have a "static" folder inside it. The "index.html" file should be directly inside the "static" folder.

Here's how your folder structure should look:

```
app/
|-- main.py
|-- static/
|   |-- index.html
```

Next, ensure that you are mounting the "**static**" directory correctly. You don't need to include the "html=True" parameter; **FastAPI will handle HTML files by default**.

Last, make sure that your FastAPI server is running and listening on the specified host and port. When you run your script with `uvicorn`, it should display something like `"Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000."`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering, I've changed my folder structure, and I've checked with postman and the server replies and listens, the only thing I'm not sure about is the directory path, I've read the FastAPI documentation, and maybe I'm just confused, but I've tried changing it to app/static as well as simply static, both don't give me an error, and it still doesn't seem to work for me, when trying to open the file.

Comment: have you try to change variable on `mount()`. ex: changing the path into `/app` not just `/`, etc

Comment: Solved it, first of all I haven't been adding the /static before localhost, second I moved my HTML file to the outside static folder, not in app directory