# How to render CSS/JS/Images along with HTML file in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I am facing an issue while rendering the HTMl file in FastAPI.

**main.py file**

```
static_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
app.mount("/",StaticFiles(directory=static_dir, html=True),name="static")

@app.get("/")
async def index():
    return FileResponse('index.html', media_type='text/html')
```

While running the above file using uvicorn I am able to render the HTML file at http://127.0.0.1:8765/, but the static files, such as css, js and images, are not getting rendered.

**index.html**: some code of HTML File (which is build from Angular JS)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.87afad25367d1df4.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.87afad25367d1df4.css"></noscript></head>
<body class="cui">
  test
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.7f95ee6540776f88.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills.a246e584d5c017d7.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.4f51d0f81827a3db.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

**File Structure:**

```
modulename
  - static
       - index.html
       - styles.87afad25367d1df4.css
       - runtime.7f95ee6540776f88.js
       - polyfills.a246e584d5c017d7.js
       - main.4f51d0f81827a3db.js
       
  - main.py 
  - __init__.py
```

When I open the browser console it show like below:
[image]

The CSS/js should be render without static included in it e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8765/styles.87afad25367d1df4.css but it run on browser it loads from  http://127.0.0.1:8765/static/styles.87afad25367d1df4.css.

I am not sure how to fix this any help will be appreciated.

**Update: Adding below code to explain it better**

**main.py**

```
import uvicorn
import os
import webbrowser
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI(
    title="UI",
    description="This is to test",
)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

static_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
app.mount("/",StaticFiles(directory=static_dir, html=True),name="static")

def start_server():
    # print('Starting Server...')       

    uvicorn.run(
        "ui.main:app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8765,
        log_level="debug",
        reload=True,
    )
    # webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8765/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

Running this file as package/module in test.py file:

```
from ui import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main.start_server()
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WingmanUi</title>
  <base href="static/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.87afad25367d1df4.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
</head>
<body>
  This is to test  
<script src="runtime.7f95ee6540776f88.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills.a246e584d5c017d7.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.4f51d0f81827a3db.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**File structure:**

```
ui
  - static
       - index.html
       - styles.87afad25367d1df4.css
       - runtime.7f95ee6540776f88.js
       - polyfills.a246e584d5c017d7.js
       - main.4f51d0f81827a3db.js
       
  - main.py 
  - __init__.py
```

Comment: @Chris No I did not added static prefix as you can see in my HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when using [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) with the `html` flag set to `True`, in order to serve static files (for dynamic webpages, see [Templates](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) instead), for instance:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static', html=True), name='static')
```

you don't have to define an endpoint to serve the index page, as `html=True` means running your app in HTML mode; thus, FastAPI/Starlette automatically loads `index.html`—see [Starlette documentation on `StaticFiles`](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/). Also, in case you need to have additional endpoints, note that [the order that endpoints are defined in your application matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804).

Second, since you have mounted your `StaticFiles` instance, specifying the `directory='static'`, then your static files are expected to be served from that directory. Hence, all you have to do is to move all your static files, along with the HTML file, inside the `static` directory. You should then be able to serve your static files as follows (given that you have mounted `StaticFiles` instance to `/`, e.g., `app.mount('/', ...`):

```html
<script src="someScript.js"></script>
```

or, if `StaticFiles` instance is mounted to `/static`, e.g., `app.mount('/static', ...)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804) as well):

```html
<script src="static/someScript.js"></script>
```

In your case, since you have mounted `StaticFiles` instance to `/`, the reason for your static files still being loaded with the `static` prefix, e.g., `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/someScript.js` is simply because you have added a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) URL in your HTML document to use for all *relative* URLs. Hence,  you should **remove the following line** from your HTML file:

```html
<base href="static/">
```