# How can I manage Vue routes inside fastapi?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, fastapi

I want to serve Vue frontend inside fastapi.

```
@app.get('/')
def home():
    try:
        return RedirectResponse("/index.html", status_code=303)
```

redirects correctly and opens web application served using:

```
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="./static", html=True), name="static")
```

Navigation works fine until a new page is opened or current page refreshed. This issue also happens when frontend and backend links are same.
For example I have same Vue route and fastapi route for link below:

```
http://localhost:8000/statistics
```

How can I manage Vue routes inside fastapi?

Comment: When setting the `html` flag in the `StaticFiles` instance to `true`, `index.html` will be automatically loaded when accessing `/` (i.e., the directory to which the `StaticFiles` instance is mounted, as shown in your example); hence, in that case, there would be no need to specify another endpoint to handle requests to that directory or sub-directories, e.g., `/images/photo.png`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911598/17865804) for more details.

Comment: The issue is that the Vue-app will have a current history of `/foo/bar`, which has been set using the History API - i.e. the URL is not a real URL, and reloading the application makes the browser request `/foo/bar` and not `/` as it originally did. I'm not sure StaticFiles can handle that use case automagically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `createWebHashHistory` at router/index.js:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
  });

  export default router;
```

When I refresh any page, it reloads without error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate what endpoints should return your Vue application and which one should return an API-response. You can do this by mounting your application under `/api` as the base path, then serve your vue application for any other endpoint:

```py
app.mount("/api", my_app)

@app.get("/{custom_path:path}")
async def serve_vue(custom_path):
    .. serve your Vue-app here
```

The reason why you have to do this is since when you reload your application, the browser makes a request for `/foo/bar` from the server - which it has no idea about how to serve unless you've registered a handler for that service.

I'd recommend doing this inside your front web server (such as nginx) instead, so that these requests never hit your app at all - that way you can also build/deploy the Vue app independent of your FastAPI application.